# Writing to CSV results in each letter having its own cell

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have some code that parses HTML with BeautifulSoup, and prints the code. [Here is the source code](https://gist.github.com/jsaue003/9717f3117a1240094920539bbd4c637a) (gist linked if interested):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

r = requests.post('https://opir.fiu.edu/instructor_evals/instr_eval_result.asp', data={'Term': '1175', 'Coll': 'CBADM'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

tables = soup.find_all('table')
print(tables)



print(tables)
```

The output of my code before exporting to CSV looks like this:

```
 Question   No Response Excellent   Very Good     
  Good   Fair    Poor   
  Description of course objectives and assignments  
  0.0%  76.1%   17.4%   6.5%    0.0%    
  0.0%  
  Communication of ideas and information    0.0%    
  78.3% 17.4%   4.3%    0.0%    0.0%
```

I really liked this output, and wanted to export it to a CSV, so I then added the following:

```
writer = csv.writer(open("C:\\Temp\\output_file.csv", 'w'))

for table in tables:
rows = table.find_all("tr")
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    if len(cells) == 7:  # this filters out rows with 'Term', 'Instructor Name' etc.
        for cell in cells:
            print(cell.text + "\t", end="") 
            writer.writerow(cell.text)
        print("")  # newline after each row
print("-------------")  # table delimiter
```

Unfortunately, this code results in each single unique character or letter having its own cell:

[image: error]

**So my question is this: how can I fix this code so that it properly exports the output to a CSV file, without adding a new cell for each and every character?** I'm not exactly sure why it is doing this. It also seems to only be exporting the very first table, and ignoring every other piece of data in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell.text` is a string, but `writerow` needs an iterable of data, so it can write each element to its own cell. Since you passed a list, each character is treated as a separate element and written to separate cells.

You'll have to wrap a `[]` around the string to get it working, so you're passing a list of a string:

```
writer.writerow([cell.text])
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3Sq4b Awesome! It looks a lot better now. Is there any [simple] way to get the percentages next to the classifications (good, fair, poor, etc) in column B?

Comment: @JSowwy Yes, there is a way to do it. You will need to load the labels and the %s into separate lists. Then you can `zip` and call writerow on each pair. If you want code, please accept my answer and open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I don't think I can ask any more questions for a while. "It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 4 days before asking again."

Comment: @JSowwy Thanks. Are you sure? Try again?

Comment: Yeah, still says the same thing. Not well received by the community error, 4 days until next question. At any rate, I will ask in 4 days when the system allows me to again.

Comment: @JSowwy Yes, good idea. Better to wait it out. At any cost, don't create another account :-)